# Error TS2724: '"@angular/core"' has no exported member named 'NgModuleFactoryLoader'. Did you mean 'NgModuleFactory'?

Tags: angular, angularjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, runtime-error

When I start my asp.net/angular project on visual studio 2022 by entering ng serve I face this issue.

```
error TS2724: '"@angular/core"' has no exported member named 'NgModuleFactoryLoader'. Did you mean 'NgModuleFactory'?
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

I upgraded my Angular version to 14.

[image: CLI Screenshot]

I deleted my module file and re-run `npm install` but didn't work. I want to run my angular project but facing this issue.

Comment: That API was removed as part of v13

Answer (score 2):

When I updated to angular 16 I found this question to resolve a similar error. I changed `renderModuleFactory` to `renderModule` in my `main.server.ts` file.

```
//main.server.ts

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

Comment: This makes the build successful but while trying to serve applition I get error saying    `TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object`

Answer (score 1):

From here: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2451

> @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader package was deprecated and removed since version 9, as this is no longer required

Just delete it and remove the reference to it in app.server.module

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace

```
const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
   ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
   : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);
```

With

```
const renderPromise = renderModule(AppServerModule, options);
```

now. The workaround isn't necessary anymore...